# Setting an alias only for current user in Unix

Tags: unix, alias

I want to create a Unix alias, that allows me for example to type `l` for `ls -l`.
Nevertheless, I do not want to modify the file `/etc/bash.bashrc` as that one applies to all users I believe.

How can I set the alias only for my user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the `~/.bashrc` file located in your home user directory. This way the alias will apply just to your user.

You can check the comprehensive information about this in https://stackoverflow.com/q/415403/1983854.

Comment: I tried to do it, adding the line `alias l='ls -l'` to that file, but I still get

`l: command not found`. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to source the file after updating. Just do this in your prompt:  `source ~/.bashrc`. New alias will be loaded.

Comment: So... did it work, @Alphaaa ?

Comment: It just worked, great!

Comment: Good to read that, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Edit ~/.bashrc to change your user settings in this way.